# My windows form application in c# won't work

Tags: c#

When I try to run (debug) the program it says:

> Error CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Form1.richTextBox1'

I want to learn how to use multiple threads in windows forms application.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Threading;


namespace test
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Thread countdown = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CountDown));

    private static SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.AppendText("A button was clicked\r\n");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        countdown.Start();
    }

    public static void CountDown()
    {
        synth.Speak("Starting!");

        for (int i = 10; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(i + "\r\n");
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
            richTextBox1.Clear();

        }
     }
  }
}
```

---

`public static void CountDown()` changed to `public void CountDown()`.

Now when I try to run (debug) the program it says:

> Error CS0236 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Form1.CountDown()'

Comment: Could you share your InitializeComponent please?

Comment: Why is the `CountDown` method `static`?  A `static` method can't access an instance member because there is no instance in that context.

Comment: well hope that you are calling the method from some other class, could you please add the statements that call the method?

Comment: i cant send my InitializeComponent. It says it is too long

Comment: i dont know what you mean by "add the statements that call the method". So sorry guys. i am really new in this!

Comment: @HappyCoconut - Please don't edit questions to make the comments and answers invalid. I've rebuilt the question so as to maintain history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue that you hit was the need to change `public static void CountDown()` to `public void CountDown()`.

That led to the field initialization issue. You can get around that by doing this:

```
    Thread countdown = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        countdown = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CountDown));
    }
```

Now your program will run, however, that'll lead you in to a new issue. You'll get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
>     HResult=-2146233079
>     Message=Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'richTextBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

You simply can't access UI elements from a non-UI thread.

You'll then need to do this:

```
    public void CountDown()
    {
        synth.Speak("Starting!");

        for (int i = 10; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            int i2 = i; // take a local copy of the loop variable
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => richTextBox1.AppendText(i2 + "\r\n")));
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => richTextBox1.Clear()));
        }
    }
```

I'd suggest trying to avoid learning how to do threading. Threading is hard and there are so many better options now.

Try using `async`/`await` and you don't need threads at all. Try this:

```
    private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        synth.Speak("Starting!");

        for (int i = 10; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(i + "\r\n");
            await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1000);
            richTextBox1.Clear();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! i really appreciate it! Have a nice day and thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Each controls that you are using in the front end are non-static members, As per the rules you need *An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property to access them inside a Static method*, Here in your case the solution is simple, Change the signature of the `CountDown` method by removing the static keyword, so that it will also became a non-static member and you can access them as required and your code will works fine as expected.

As per this the signature of the `CountDown` would be like this:

```
public void CountDown()
{
    // Code here       
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the ansers guys! i really appreciate it.  However when i remove the startic and i get another error now : Error CS0236 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Form1.CountDown()'

Answer (score -1):

on button 1 click
[image]

on button 2 click

[image]
`

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

private static SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.AppendText("A button was clicked\r\n");
}

private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CountDown();
}

public void CountDown()
{

synth.Speak("Starting!");

    for (int i = 10; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        richTextBox1.AppendText(i + "\r\n");
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
        richTextBox1.Clear();

    }



 }
}
}`
```

Comment: first of all thank you for your answer! However when i copy this code the program starts but the button 2 doesn't do anything...

Comment: This will lead to the `"Cross-thread operation not valid"` error.

Comment: @Enigmativity yes you are right. Updated the answer. Removed Thread but it meets the requirement

Comment: @HappyCoconut Check with the updated answer

Comment: Hey i checked with the updated answer and the button 2 doesn't do anything!

Comment: @HappyCoconut when i tried with my sample i get the output. check the screen shot

Comment: @sibysunny - Now you're blocking the UI thread so that it appears to be doing  nothing.